# How to generate CSDL and MSL files programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, edmx

I'm trying to achieve the dynamic ORM models generation using C# language. I need this because of the tasks in my work.

I've achieved how to create SSDL file programmatically in C#. I'm using `EntityStoreSchemaGenerator` class, which is writing data this way:

```
var store = new EntityStoreSchemaGenerator(providerInvariantName, connectionString, "ShoppingModel");
store.GenerateStoreMetadata();
store.WriteStoreSchema(filePath);
```

I can show you the sample SSDL file I've got: http://pastebin.com/3U4A6fY9

That's OK, but how about to get CSDL and MSL files?

As I understood, it's required to use `EntityModelSchemaGenerator` class for such an aim from the `System.Data.Entity.Design` namespace for generating CSDL and MSL files.

If to look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.entitymodelschemagenerator_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

There are couple of methods:

- WriteModelSchema(String) Writes the generated conceptual schema definition language (CSDL) to the specified file.
- WriteModelSchema(XmlWriter)  Writes the generated conceptual schema definition language (CSDL) to an XmlWriter object.
- WriteStorageMapping(String)  Writes the generated mapping specification language (MSL) to the specified file.
- WriteStorageMapping(XmlWriter)   Writes the generated mapping specification language (MSL) to an XmlWriter object.

Which may be used for generating the required files (CSDL && MSL).
But I'm rather confused... How to generate them, if `EntityModelSchemaGenerator` constructor requires `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityContainer`.

As I understood, I must prepare some entity container using the `EntityConnection` class.

But, how can I build the entity connection, which requires all metadata files to be already created ( *.csdl, *.ssdl, *.msl ), if my aim is to create *.csdl & *.msl files previously?

So I can't use the `EntityModelSchemaGenerator` until I create all metadata files? So what's the way to create *.csdl and *.msl files ( *.ssdl file is done )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem using the

`Models = new EntityModelSchemaGenerator(Store.StoreItemCollection, "ShoppingModelConceptual", "ShoppingModelConceptualContainer");`

Which is based on previously prepared store item collection.

http://pastebin.com/B0gbzuin

```
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Design;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace DynamicOrm1
{
    class Generators
    {
        internal EntityModelSchemaGenerator Models { get; set; }
        internal EntityClassGenerator Classes { get; set; }
        internal EntityCodeGenerator Code { get; set; }
        internal EntityViewGenerator Views { get; set; }
        internal EntityStoreSchemaGenerator Store { get; set; }

        const string connectionString = "Server = MSSQL2014; Database = test.shop; Trusted_Connection = True;";
        const string providerInvariantName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

        public Generators()
        {
            InitializeSettings();
        }

        private void InitializeSettings()
        {
            Classes = new EntityClassGenerator(LanguageOption.GenerateCSharpCode);
            Code = new EntityCodeGenerator(LanguageOption.GenerateCSharpCode);
            Views = new EntityViewGenerator(LanguageOption.GenerateCSharpCode);
            Store = new EntityStoreSchemaGenerator(providerInvariantName, connectionString, "ShoppingModelStore");

            Store.GenerateForeignKeyProperties = true;
        }

        internal void CreateSsdlFile(string filePath)
        {
            if (filePath == String.Empty)
                throw new Exception("Can't create the SSDL file, because the given file path is an empty string.");

            Store.GenerateStoreMetadata();
            Store.WriteStoreSchema(filePath);
        }

        internal void CreateCsdlAndMslFile(string csdlFilePath, string mslFilePath)
        {
            if (Store == null)
                throw new Exception("Can't create the CSDL and MSL files, because the `Store` object is null.");

            Models = new EntityModelSchemaGenerator(Store.StoreItemCollection, "ShoppingModelConceptual", "ShoppingModelConceptualContainer");
            Models.GenerateMetadata();
            Models.WriteModelSchema(csdlFilePath);
            Models.WriteStorageMapping(mslFilePath);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static Generators EntityGenerators { get; set; }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                EntityGenerators = new Generators();
                EntityGenerators.CreateSsdlFile(@"\shopping.ssdl.xml");
                EntityGenerators.CreateCsdlAndMslFile(@"\shopping.csdl.xml", @"\shopping.msl.xml");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use `Code` for generating my `cs` file, how can i pass the edmx for `Code.GenerateCode`? (First parameter)